# Using ggplot2 to create dodged chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data has the following representation:

```
test_number;instance_1;instance_2 #field names
test_1;2;3
test_2;5;6
test_3;3;9
...
```

I want to represent my results in a way that the results for instance_1 and instance_2 can be represented side by side for each test instance.

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for. So for each occurrence in `test_number` you want to see a side by side for `instance_` and `instance_2`? You want all the various `test_`, `test_2`,... side by side?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you'll want to do is rearrange your data for `ggplot` - it needs to be long and not wide. To do this, we'll us the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

So here's your data now,

```
df_untidy=data.frame(test_number=1:3,instance_1=c(2,3,5),instance_2=c(3,6,9))

test_number instance_1 instance_2
1           1          2          3
2           2          3          6
3           3          5          9
```

We combine the `instance` columns into a single column,

```
df_tidy <- df_untidy %>% gather(instance,value,-test_number)

test_number   instance value
1           1 instance_1     2
2           2 instance_1     3
3           3 instance_1     5
4           1 instance_2     3
5           2 instance_2     6
6           3 instance_2     9
```

Then it's simple to plot this with `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data=df_tidy,aes(x=factor(test_number),y=value,fill=factor(instance) )) +geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')
```

[image]